# PrimeNg mega-menu auto display

Tags: angular, menu, primeng, megamenu

I am looking for a way to display PrimeNg Angular Mega menu on hover. Default behaviour is display on item click. Theses attributes exists on menubar components https://primeng.org/menubar with `autoDisplay`, `autoHide` and `autoHideDelay` properties.

It's also exist on Primefaces JSF component https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/megamenu
Should I inherit the megamenu component to add this missing behaviour or is there a easier way to do this?

*I use PrimeNg 16.9.1*